# I cannot run a ELF-format program .The shell tells me no such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc

My environment is Ubuntu 14 32bits.
I write three c files called main.c,foo.c,and bar.c respectively.
the codes are very simple.
The first source code is main.c

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 extern void foo();
 int main(){
 foo();
 return 0;
}
```

the second source code is foo.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(){
printf("Hi,I am foo.");
bar();
}
```

the last one is bar.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void bar(){
printf("Hi,I am bar.");
}
```

All the files above are be put into the same folder called test.
(its absolute path is /home/jack/Desktop/test)
then I issue the commands :

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libbar.so.1 -o libbar.so.1.0.0 bar.c
$ ln -s libbar.so.1.0.0 libbar.so
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.0 foo.c -lbar -L.
$ ln -s libfoo.so.1.0.0  libfoo.so
$ gcc -c main.c
$ ld -rpath /home/jack/Desktop/test -e main -o main main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar
```

then I run the executable file called main.

```
$./main
```

but the shell return the string below

> bash: ./main: no such file or directory.

But the main file really exists in the current directory.

Why?

Comment: @SantoshA `gcc -c main.c` does not generate `a.out`. It does not generate any executable file at all. It only compiles the source file `main.c` and generates the object file `main.o`.

Comment: You need to link `crt0.o` and other things. `gcc` is doing that for you. Use `gcc -v`  to understand what is happening.

Comment: @newbie: please **edit your question** to motivate it. **Why do you do that**, and why don't you use `gcc`  to compile and link your program?

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of `file main` if your distribution has `file`?

Comment: Hi,@SantoshA,Thanks for you comment.I just want to experience the process of linking.So I use gcc -c parameter, and use ld tool to link main.o and other objects together.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch,Hi,While using gcc to compile and link program is very very convenient,I  want to know what should be done if I link them using ld by myself.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Normally you should not invoke `ld` directly.  Instead you should use `gcc` to do the link.  `gcc` passes some special options to the linker.

If I modify your script to use the correct sonames and to use `gcc` to link, it works.  I did this:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libbar.so.1.0.0 -o libbar.so.1.0.0 bar.c
ln -s libbar.so.1.0.0 libbar.so
gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1.0.0 -o libfoo.so.1.0.0 foo.c -lbar -L.
ln -s libfoo.so.1.0.0  libfoo.so
gcc -c main.c
gcc -Wl,-rpath,$(pwd) -o main main.o -L$(pwd) -lfoo -lbar
```

Using `ld` directly is for unusual situations.  Don't do it.  That said, offhand I do not know what as wrong with your approach.  I think `-e` is wrong here -- you don't want to invoke main directly, `_start` does some other things.  Looking at the output of `ldd` shows some important differences between the two approaches.  Invoking the link using `gcc -v` will show you a bit of what is happening behind the scenes, in case you want to understand some more.

Comment: Hi,@Tom Tromey,modifying the parameter -Wl,-soname,libbar.so.1 to  -Wl,-soname,libbar.so.1.0.0 may be not proper.I rememer that soname generally only contains the major version number.Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> bash: ./main: no such file or directory.
> ```
>
> But the main file really exists in the current directory.
>
> Why?

The executable needs a suitable program interpreter to be able to perform dynamic linking. The `no such file or directory` message is printed because the default interpreter, which is wrong, can't be found.

Set it with the `ld` option `-dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2` (for 32 bit).

64 bit dynamic linker is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.

As your entry is directly `main` you must call `exit(0)` at the end of `main`. It can't be returned from main because noone has called it. The instruction pointer was directly set to the address of `main` by the kernel.  Returning from `main` would probably result in a segfault and since you did not add a `\n` to the printf's the messages could not be seen.

Comment: Hi,you perfectly solve my problem.when I add the ld option -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 ,the program main works,but as you say,the segment fault happens because I forget to call exit .Thanks for you help.Thanks.